# Populate select drop down based on previous selection of first dropdown angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I am having issues populating the 2nd of two drop down's with data. The first drop down has me select a from a list of Sessions, every Session has ReportFiles attached to it like the model below:

```
export interface ExceptionReportSessionData {
  SessionName: string,
  ReportFiles: Array<string>
}
```

Based on what Session the user selects I want the 2nd drop down to fill with the ReportFiles associated with the selected Session. I have no issues getting the data for Sessions. Its the second drop down that will not return any data.

Here is what I have so far.
Component.ts:

```
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {



 public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = [];
  newData: any;
  reports = [];

  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {
  }

  public async getExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<void> {
    return this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionData = data;
        });

  }  


  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getExceptionReportSessionData();

  }

  sessionDataChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    console.log(`session index: ${value}`);
    console.log(this.sessionData);
    if (isNaN(Number(value))) {
      this.reports = [];
    } else {
      this.reports = this.sessionData[Number(value)].ReportFiles;
    }
    console.log(this.reports);
  }


}
```

Sidenote: When I log (`reports: ${this.reports}`) it shows it as undefined and I cannot figure out why which is the main issue in returning the data in my second drop down

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="input-group">
    <h4>Session: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"
            (change)="sessionDataChange($event)">
      <option value="null">Select session...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let session of sessionData; index as i;"
              value="{{i}}">
        {{session.sessionName}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <h4>Report Date: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01">
      <option value="">Select report date...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let report of reports"
              value="report">
        {{report}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another side note: The retrieve button will eventually be making an API call sending the data selected from the drop downs.

Comment: have you console log / checked this.sessionData[Number(value)].ReportFiles; this thing is returning value ?

Comment: @LogicBlower I am realizing now that 
 `this.sessionData[Number(value)].ReportFiles` isn't returning any value. Which means `sessionData` isn't storing any data from my `getExceptionReportSessionData()` method. How can I get `sessionData` to store data from `getExceptionReportSessionData()`?

Comment: console.log(this.sessionData) - what does this return ? , and this api is called before you change the first dropdown ?

Comment: @LogicBlower it returns 'undefined'

Comment: this means your data (GetExceptionReportSessionData())  variable is returning null response  ? so i guess first you need a valid response ?

Comment: @LogicBlower but if I `console.log(this.sessionData)` inside of the `getExceptionReportSessionData()` function it returns the correct array of data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215537/discussion-between-logicblower-and-jaden-adams).

Comment: try it like first you see in console that session data value is printed , then change the value of the dropdown and console.log session data just before you are assigning to reports